# Windows phone 7 reading XML with XDocument

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hi im trying to make my first windows phone 7 app. It involves querying a server about flight information. Then receiving a XML document. I then want to create a series of objects based on the XML I get back. However there is a problem since the object values are blank.

My Code

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        getResults("http://test.com/");
    }

    public void getResults(string websiteURL)
    {
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(websiteURL));
        c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void c_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            string s = e.Result;
            XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)));
            // So something with the XML we get back
            XDocument data = XDocument.Load(r);
            var ns = data.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            var flights = from query in data.Descendants(ns+"Flight")
                              select new Flight
                              {
                                  AircraftType = (int)query.Element(ns + "AircraftType"),
                                  ArrivalTerminal = (int)query.Element(ns + "ArrivalTerminal"),
                                  Carrier = (string)query.Element(ns + "Carrier"),
                                  DepartureTerminal = (int)query.Element(ns + "DepartureTerminal"),
                                  Duration = (string)query.Element(ns + "Duration"),
                                  EndDateTime = (string)query.Element(ns + "EndDateTime"),
                                  EndPoint = (string)query.Element(ns + "EndPoint"),
                                  FlightIndexNo = (int)query.Element(ns + "FlightIndexNo"),
                                  FlightNo = (int)query.Element(ns + "FlightNo"),
                                  NumStops = (int)query.Element(ns + "NumStops"),
                                  OperatedBy = (string)query.Element(ns + "OperatedBy"),
                                  StartDateTime = (string)query.Element(ns + "StartDateTime"),
                                  StartPoint = (string)query.Element(ns + "StartPoint")
                              };
            //checking if anything is there.
            string result ="";

            foreach (Flight i in flights)
            {
                result += i.Carrier;
            }
            resultsBlock.Text = result;


        }
    }

    public class Flight
    {
        public int aircraftType;
        public int arrivalTerminal;
        public string carrier;
        public int departureTerminal;
        public string duration;
        public string endDateTime;
        public string endPoint;
        public int flightIndexNo;
        public int flightNo;
        public int numStops;
        public string operatedBy;
        public string startDateTime;
        public string startPoint;

        //Getter and setters
```

and the section of XML I want looks like this. This is also the first use of the Flight tag in the XML. Added the start of the XML whole thing is hundreds of lines long so won't but it all up. The Flight Tag I want is burred down in there.

```
<FindFlightsResponse xmlns="urn:webjet.com.au" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DisplayMessage i:nil="true" />
<OutboundFlightInfo>
          ...
              <Flight>
                    <AircraftType>734</AircraftType>
                    <ArrivalTerminal>3</ArrivalTerminal>
                    <Carrier>QF</Carrier>
                    <DepartureTerminal>1</DepartureTerminal>
                    <Duration>PT1H25M</Duration>
                    <EndDateTime>2011-04-20T07:25:00</EndDateTime>
                    <EndPoint>SYD</EndPoint>
                    <FlightIndexNo>1</FlightIndexNo>
                    <FlightNo>400</FlightNo>
                    <NumStops>0</NumStops>
                    <OperatedBy>QF</OperatedBy>
                    <StartDateTime>2011-04-20T06:00:00</StartDateTime>
                    <StartPoint>MEL</StartPoint>
                </Flight>
```

I've probably made some simple mistake. 
All help appreciated.
Thanks.
edit im now getting a method passing error. I changed the datetime to string for simplicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're not showing us the complete XML and it likely has a default namespace specified. A namespace will look like `xmlns="http://www.domain.com"`. If this is indeed the case then your LINQ to XML queries need to reference that namespace, and this can be done as follows:

```
var ns = data.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var flights = from query in data.Descendants(ns + "Flight")
              select new Flight
              {
                  AircraftType = (int)query.Element(ns + "AircraftType"),
                  ArrivalTerminal = (int)query.Element(ns + "ArrivalTerminal"),
                  Carrier = (string)query.Element(ns + "Carrier"),
                  DepartureTerminal = (int)query.Element(ns + "DepartureTerminal"),
                  Duration = (string)query.Element(ns + "Duration"),
                  EndDateTime = (DateTime)query.Element(ns + "EndDateTime"),
                  EndPoint = (string)query.Element(ns + "EndPoint"),
                  FlightIndexNo = (int)query.Element(ns + "FlightIndexNo"),
                  FlightNo = (int)query.Element(ns + "FlightNo"),
                  NumStops = (int)query.Element(ns + "NumStops"),
                  OperatedBy = (string)query.Element(ns + "OperatedBy"),
                  StartDateTime = (DateTime)query.Element(ns + "StartDateTime"),
                  StartPoint = (string)query.Element(ns + "StartPoint")
              };
```

Notice that you need to prefix each element name with the namespace, hence the use of `ns +` throughout the code.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad you're right there was a namespace specified. However I made the changes and still have the same problem

Comment: @user704314 can you update your question with the changes made and show more of the XML with the namespace?

Comment: I have updated the code and changed the datetime arguments for simplicity because now I get a error saying FormatException was unhandled when I create a new Flight.

Comment: @user704314 I think something else might be causing the exception, probably in the Flight class or something down the line that uses it. To verify I suggest placing a breakpoint after the query and checking the `flights` result. If it fails before hitting the breakpoint then something is likely off as part of the query. In fact, you could comment out `Flight` and use an anonymous type temporarily to verify that the query is working like this: `select new //Flight`. That much should work and reveal where the problem is by then removing the comments from `Flight` and inspecting the code.